# PCM S16 LE (s16l) to GSM610 Conversion using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to convert audio from PCM to GSM using NAudio. In that, I am getting this error:

> AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Souce audio details.
 **Codec**: PCM S16 LE (s16l)
 **Channel**: Mono
 **Sample rate**: 22050 Hz
 **Bits per sample**: 16
**OS**: Windows 10

```
string inFile = @"E:\temp\in.wav";
string outFile = @"E:\temp\out.wav";

var reader = new WaveFileReader(inFile);
var writer = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new Gsm610WaveFormat(), reader);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outFile, writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

`WaveFormatConversionStream` uses the ACM drivers that are installed on your system. The `AcmNotPossible` error means that no driver that could make that conversion was present. So the most likely explanation is that your version of Windows does not have a GSM codec (or at least one that supports that particular conversion). The NAudio demo project (a WinForms app) has a page that will enumerate the installed codecs and show the supported conversions.

Comment: Thanks! Mark , Got your point, I will try to install GSM codec in windows 10 and check.